# Accidentally did rm -r ~/.Trash

Tags: macos, terminal, trash

What should I do now? Will my computer be okay?

Comment: well at least you specified to rm the Trash only, unlike some who do rm- rf and then wonder what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the system will recreate it automatically.

Actually about `.Trash`, it is located on every drive you will connect to your Mac and where you will delete some files. Deleted files on external drive won't show in your local `.Trash`.